# man -k generates strange results - makewhatis is looking at files?

Tags: command-line

When I run man -k (apropos), `makewhatis` gives this weird output:

```
...
ps2pdfwr(1)              - Convert PostScript to PDF without specifying CompatibilityLevel, using ghostscript
roff2pdf(1)              - transform roff code into pdf mode t .ds EL N'188'" .ds EL .|.|."
texi2dvi(1)              - convert Texinfo documents to DVI or PDF
tiff2pdf(1)              - convert a TIFF image to a PDF document
dvipdf(1)                - Convert TeX DVI file to PDF using ghostscript and dvips
gs(1)                    - Ghostscript (PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer)
gsnd(1)                  - Run ghostscript (PostScript and PDF engine) without display
pdf2dsc(1)               - generate a PostScript page list of a PDF document
:makewhatis: /Library/TeX/texbin/man: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/./libgutenprint.2.dylib: No such file or directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.0.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libldap.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcom_err.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libresolv.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmpagent.dylib: Not a directory
...
```

So that's pretty weird.

But I do not have a MANPATH defined:

```
% printenv | grep MAN
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
%
```

`/etc/manpaths` isn't at fault:

```
% cat /etc/manpaths
/usr/share/man
/usr/local/share/man
%
```

And here is `/etc/man.conf`:

```
simsong@nimi Simson Medical Records % cat /etc/man.conf
#
# Generated automatically from man.conf.in by the
# configure script.
#
# man.conf from man-1.6g
#
# For more information about this file, see the man pages man(1)
# and man.conf(5).
#
# This file is read by man to configure the default manpath (also used
# when MANPATH contains an empty substring), to find out where the cat
# pages corresponding to given man pages should be stored,
# and to map each PATH element to a manpath element.
# It may also record the pathname of the man binary. [This is unused.]
# The format is:
#
# MANBIN        pathname
# MANPATH       manpath_element [corresponding_catdir]
# MANPATH_MAP       path_element    manpath_element
#
# If no catdir is given, it is assumed to be equal to the mandir
# (so that this dir has both man1 etc. and cat1 etc. subdirs).
# This is the traditional Unix setup.
# Certain versions of the FSSTND recommend putting formatted versions
# of /usr/.../man/manx/page.x into /var/catman/.../catx/page.x.
# The keyword FSSTND will cause this behaviour.
# Certain versions of the FHS recommend putting formatted versions of
# /usr/.../share/man/[locale/]manx/page.x into
# /var/cache/man/.../[locale/]catx/page.x.
# The keyword FHS will cause this behaviour (and overrides FSSTND).
# Explicitly given catdirs override.
#
# FSSTND
FHS
#
# This file is also read by man in order to find how to call nroff, less, etc.,
# and to determine the correspondence between extensions and decompressors.
#
# MANBIN        /usr/local/bin/man
#
# Every automatically generated MANPATH includes these fields
#
MANPATH /usr/share/man
MANPATH /usr/local/share/man
MANPATH /usr/X11/man
MANPATH /Library/Apple/usr/share/man
#
# Uncomment if you want to include one of these by default
#
# MANPATH   /opt/*/man
# MANPATH   /usr/lib/*/man
# MANPATH   /usr/share/*/man
# MANPATH   /usr/kerberos/man
#
# Set up PATH to MANPATH mapping
#
# If people ask for "man foo" and have "/dir/bin/foo" in their PATH
# and the docs are found in "/dir/man", then no mapping is required.
#
# The below mappings are superfluous when the right hand side is
# in the mandatory manpath already, but will keep man from statting
# lots of other nearby files and directories.
#
MANPATH_MAP /bin            /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /sbin           /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/bin        /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/sbin       /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/local/bin      /usr/local/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/local/sbin     /usr/local/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/X11/bin        /usr/X11/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/bin/X11        /usr/X11/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/bin/mh     /usr/share/man
#
# NOAUTOPATH keeps man from automatically adding directories that look like
# manual page directories to the path.
#
#NOAUTOPATH
#
# NOCACHE keeps man from creating cache pages ("cat pages")
# (generally one enables/disable cat page creation by creating/deleting
# the directory they would live in - man never does mkdir)
#
#NOCACHE
#
# Useful paths - note that COL should not be defined when
# NROFF is defined as "groff -Tascii" or "groff -Tlatin1";
# not only is it superfluous, but it actually damages the output.
# For use with utf-8, NROFF should be "nroff -mandoc" without -T option.
# (Maybe - but today I need -Tlatin1 to prevent double conversion to utf8.)
#
# If you have a new troff (version 1.18.1?) and its colored output
# causes problems, add the -c option to TROFF, NROFF, JNROFF.
#
TROFF       /usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc -c
NROFF       /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c
JNROFF      /usr/bin/groff -Tnippon -mandocj -c
EQN     /usr/bin/eqn -Tps
NEQN        /usr/bin/eqn -Tascii
JNEQN       /usr/bin/eqn -Tnippon
TBL     /usr/bin/tbl
# COL       /usr/bin/col
REFER       /usr/bin/refer
PIC     /usr/bin/pic
VGRIND
GRAP
PAGER       /usr/bin/less -is
BROWSER     /usr/bin/less -is
HTMLPAGER   /bin/cat
CAT     /bin/cat
#
# The command "man -a xyzzy" will show all man pages for xyzzy.
# When CMP is defined man will try to avoid showing the same
# text twice. (But compressed pages compare unequal.)
#
CMP     /usr/bin/cmp -s
#
# Compress cat pages
#
COMPRESS    /usr/local/bin/xz
COMPRESS_EXT    .xz
#
# Default manual sections (and order) to search if -S is not specified
# and the MANSECT environment variable is not set.
#
MANSECT     1:1p:8:2:3:3p:4:5:6:7:9:0p:tcl:n:l:p:o
#
# Default options to use when man is invoked without options
# This is mainly for the benefit of those that think -a should be the default
# Note that some systems have /usr/man/allman, causing pages to be shown twice.
#
#MANDEFOPTIONS  -a
#
# Decompress with given decompressor when input file has given extension
# The command given must act as a filter.
#
.gz     /usr/bin/gunzip -c
.bz2        /usr/bin/bzip2 -c -d
.lzma
.z
.Z      /usr/bin/zcat
.F
.Y
.xz
```

Comment: The problem isn’t `man` but your install of whatever `makewhatis` is or is related to.  It’s looking for directories and files that don’t exist.

Comment: makewhatis isn't being called by man -k

Comment: @klanomath my problem is *not* that I am running on a read-only file system.